# create 2D repeated pattern using rectangle or lines with actionscript 3 Flash cs6

Tags: actionscript-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuWEy.jpg)

Hi Everyone,
I would like to create a 2D pattern as per the size of the brick. Which is in this example 190 length X 60 Height. I have a Preview area which is 400 Length X 300 Height. I have a mask for the preview area so anything outside of this preview area will be hidden. I have a code so far which shows the first rectangle / brick correctly as a child movieclip of the preview movieclip into the preview area sizewise and locationwise.
But I can not find an easy way to duplicate or clone this brick movieclip to achieve the pattern shown in the attached image. This actions happens on a button's click event. Any sort of help is greatly appreciated. I also would like to clean this preview area first for any previously shown preview. I have a for loop to removechild but it only removes one at a time.
thanks a lot in advance.

```
//Checks if all required textfields have valid data -- if yes then true else false
if(Vdata == true){
    //Here I should check and clean the preview area and any children previously added.
    var Pview_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip; //Main moiveclip which holds all rectangles.
    Pview_mc.name = "Pview_mc"; //name the instance so that easy to remove later on.
    var rectangle:MovieClip = new MovieClip; // initializing the variable
    rectangle.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x990000, 1); //defines line style (thickness, colour, alpha)
    rectangle.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, Number(Txt_ST.text),Number(Txt_HT.text)); // (x spacing, y spacing, width, height)
    Pview_mc.addChild(rectangle); // adds rectangle to Pview_mc movieclip
    Preview_Area.addChild(Pview_mc); // adds the Pview_mc to the Preview_Area MovieClip
    rectangle.y = rectangle.y-Number(Txt_HT.text); // positions the rectangle. 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made quick and dirty implementation of brick pattern drawing function. It is not optimized, just draws the pattern you want.

For simplicity, i do not use child objects and just draw directrly to the MovieClip. The function clears and draw pattern on each call. The following image shows possible result.

[image: draw_bricks() result]

**Draw function:**

```
// graphics      - Object to draw to
// origin_x      - Center of the top left brick
// origin_y      - Center of the top left brick
// brick_count_u - Number of bricks along the x-axis
// brick_count_v - Number of brick along the y-axis
// brick_w       - Brick width
// brick_h       - Brick height
// gap           - Brick gap
function draw_bricks(
    graphics      :Graphics,
    origin_x      :Number,
    origin_y      :Number,
    brick_count_u :int,
    brick_count_v :int,
    brick_w       :Number,
    brick_h       :Number,
    gap           :Number) :void
{
    graphics.clear();
    graphics.lineStyle(0.0, 0x00FF00, 1.0);
    //
    // For every brick along y-axis
    for (var v :int = 0; v < brick_count_v; v += 1) {
        //
        //            [ row ordinate ]---|
        //                               |
        //  [ base offset ]---|          |
        //                    |          |
        //                    v          v
        var brick_y :Number = origin_y + ((brick_h + gap) * v);
        //
        // For every brick along x-axis
        for (var u :int = 0; u < brick_count_u; u += 1) {
            //
            //          [ odd row offset ]---|
            //                               |     [ column abscissa ]---|
            //  [ base offset ]---|          |                           |
            //                    |          |                           |
            //                    v          v                           v
            var brick_x :Number = origin_x - (brick_w * 0.5 * (v % 2)) + ((brick_w + gap) * u);
            //
            // Draw brick centered at {brick_x, brick_y}
            graphics.drawRect(brick_x - brick_w * 0.5, brick_y - brick_h * 0.5, brick_w, brick_h);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var bricks :MovieClip = new MovieClip;
addChild(bricks);
draw_bricks(bricks.graphics, 0.0, 0.0, 8, 8, 190.0, 60.0, 10.0);
```

If you do not actually need display object hierarchy for this brick wall i suggest you to use this approach because this way you do not need to remove or create any "brick objects", you can just refresh single masked display object.

Note: You still need to compute optimal brick count for each axis.
Note: Remember that in flash x-axis points right and y-axis points down.

Comment: Thank you Alexander. I would say that is not at all quick and dirty. It is very appropriate, clear and simple logic you have put together. Awesome. I need to work on this code a lot based on your suggestion since I am just a beginner and I do not have formal learning about programming. But your example is a perfect start. I have made some changes to your code to position the final pattern to the desired location just to make myself clearer. I will post my final output once it is done. This pattern is just the first one. There are total 20 patterns at least. y-axis opposite to acad which sucks.